# My form's app.config only gets saved if the application crashes

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

This is a C# winform that automates tasks for me on a page. So far everything works but the app.config. I want it to store my login info locally (will be encrypted later in development) but also allow me to change my credentials when they expire. The problem is that the application crashes ONLY on the first launch after changes are made to the app.config file.

Configuration defined here at the top of the form:

```
    public Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Application.ExecutablePath);
```

And login handling via a 2nd popup form:

```
    if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["userName"] != null)
            {
                //Sends credentials from appsettings
                uName.SendKeys(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["userName"]);
                pWord.SendKeys(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["userPass"]);
                loginButton.Click();
            }
            else
            {
                //Displays modal login popup form.
                using (popupForm popup = new popupForm())
                {
                    //Displays the popup form to get login info.
                    popup.ShowDialog();

                    //Sets appsettings for credentials.
                    config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("userName", userUname);
                    config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("userPass", userPword);
                    config.Save();

                    uName.SendKeys(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["userName"]);
                    pWord.SendKeys(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["userPass"]);
                    loginButton.Click();
                }
            }
```

And it works, but only after it crashes with a null exception on the 2nd instance of uName.SendKeys(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["userName"]); in the else clause. As long as it crashes there and I test again without rebuilding, every other run will pass the =! null condition at the top of the block and log me in normally.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT1: I am realizing that my Configuration is not user-scope, but application-scope which can't change on runtime. How do I change this to be user-scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following and it works:

```
    if (Properties.Settings.Default.loginUname != null)
            {
                //Sends credentials from appsettings
                uName.SendKeys(Properties.Settings.Default.loginUname);
                pWord.SendKeys(Properties.Settings.Default.loginPword);
                loginButton.Click();
            }
            else
            {
                //Displays modal login popup form.
                using (popupForm popup = new popupForm())
                {
                    //Displays the popup form to get login info.
                    popup.ShowDialog();

                    //Sets appsettings for credentials.
                    Properties.Settings.Default.loginUname = userUname;
                    Properties.Settings.Default.loginPword = userPword;
                    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

                    uName.SendKeys(Properties.Settings.Default.loginUname);
                    pWord.SendKeys(Properties.Settings.Default.loginPword);
                    loginButton.Click();
                }
            }
```

Now it just needs security so the credentials aren't in plaintext.